# ffmpeg - Converting series of images to video (Ubuntu)

Tags: ffmpeg

I got pictures named as

```
pic_0_new.jpg
pic_10_new.jpg
pic_20_new.jpg
...
pic_1050_new.jpg
```

which I want to turn into a video (Ubuntu ffmpeg). I tried the following

```
ffmpeg -start_number 0 -i pic_%d_new.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

but I don't know how to set the step size and the end number. How to do this?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files are named with leading zeroes then you can use the built-in globbing functionality. If not (like your's), you can create a file list and supply that as the input, just like [explained here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

The other thing you need to set is the input framerate that tells FFmpeg what framerate should assume for the images (note that the option is ahead of the `-i` input option).

So the command should look like this:

```
    ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i pic_%04d_new.jpg <encoding_settings> test.avi
```

Also note that you can use the filename expansion on files with or without leading zeroes (Thanks for @Gyan to pointing it out):

- match regularly numbered files: `%d` (this is what you're using)

  ```
  img_%d.png // This will match files with any number as a postfix starting from img_0.png
  ```
- match leading zeroes: `%0<number_of_digits>d`

  ```
  img_%03d.png // This will match files ranging from img_000.png to img_999.png
  ```

In addition, mpeg4/avi is not the most convenient encoder/container to use...

Comment: *%d is incorrect* --> `%d` is the correct format when numbering has no padding.

Comment: Thanks, I did not remember that, I always use leading zeroes. I modified my answer accordingly.